# shift data in excel using two columns that create a relation with a third column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 3,000 posts in an excel spreadsheet and I also have a list of images associated to some of them.

My 3,000 posts have an unique id (say column A 1 to 3,000 is the ID)

My images, each one have an id of the post it relates to in Column B and in column C it has the image url)

I want to make some kind of function that will allow me to put say in column D the image that has an id that matches the id in column A. That way I can match the image that belongs to certain post in column A.

This is an example of what I got

```
id_article  article_related id_pic
1           1               1.jpg
2           4               2.jpg
3           15              3.jpg
4           17              4.jpg
5           20              5.jpg
6           21              6.jpg
14          23              7.jpg
15          27              8.jpg
16          31              11.jpg
```

on this example, C4 (3.jpg) should be on D9, row in which id_article:15 is on A9.

I tried to follow this steps https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Create-a-relationship-between-tables-in-Excel-fe1b6be7-1d85-4add-a629-8a3848820be3?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE in creating a relationship between column A and B but after that i had to create a pivot table which never worked.

Comment: Why you don't want to use the VLOOKUP function? It seems to be the easy way to do what you want, since your data is very simple.

Comment: right now i'm trying to research arround how vlookup works because I think it could be the answer but I don't have a clue how it works. I'm trying to use this =VLOOKUP(C2, A2:B3923, 2, FALSE) which is suppose to work, its from a similar questions here but it doesn't work for some reason so I'm trying to see if I fully understand that funcion else I'm still stuck, thanks for the suggest though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### VLOOKUP function

As I see it, you have 2 related tables (consider splitting your data as follows):

- Articles `id_article; article_picture` (Result table)
- Pictures `article_related; id_pic` (Lookup table)

You want to add a picture filename to the related article. So those picture file names, whose `id_article = article_related`.

You can use the VLOOKUP function to get the result.
Syntax: `VLOOKUP (lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])`.

In the result table (say in column D) you put your `VLOOKUP` formula.

- The `lookup_value` is the cell with the `id_article` in the Result table.
- The `table_array` is the Lookup table. Note the `article_related` must be the leftmost column, since the `VLOOKUP` only searches the leftmost column.
- The `col_index_num` is = *2*, i.e. the 2nd column from the `table_array`.
- The `[range_lookup]` is = *FALSE*, i.e. *Exact match*.

### Example

In D2 `=VLOOKUP(A2, $B$2:$C$3000, 2, FALSE)`. I recommend putting the columns B and C in a separate table.

### Explanation and links:

[MS VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

In its simplest form, the VLOOKUP function says:

> =VLOOKUP(Value you want to look up, range where you want to lookup the value, the column number in the range containing the return value,
>   Exact Match or Approximate Match – indicated as 0/FALSE or 1/TRUE).